# "X and Y" implies conditional

Tags: conditional-constructions

> Sequential disasters can also reinforce each other. Heat, droughts and flooding are often connected: hot air picks up more moisture; **dry out soil enough and water will run off it like concrete**. (From [The Economist](https://www.economist.com/the-economist-explains/2023/07/19/what-happens-when-extreme-weather-hits-several-places-at-once))

I'm not sure I understand the highlighted part correctly.

1. If **you** dry out soil... then water will...
2. If **hot air** drys out... then...

In which way would you understand this sentence?

Answer (score 2):

I’d say that your two suggested paraphrases are equivalent. That kind of *you* construct is essentially agentless, or anyway agent-agnostic. Consider

> If you square a negative number, the result is positive.

It can be understood to describe what happens when one (*you*) performs some calculation. But it also has the sense of

> The square of a negative number is positive.

It’s a bit like the meaning of pronominal verbs in, say, French or Spanish:

> *Le français se parle ici*

*literally* translates as “French speaks itself here.” But its actual meaning is “French is spoken here,” or “Here there are French speakers.”

Comment: Interpretation (1) is the normal paraphrase, but it feels a little weird. It's like saying "you" have super powers.  So isn't it that (2) makes more sense?

Comment: @ForOU - when we use 'you' in that way, we are not referring to any person, and we can discuss things that no real person is able to do.

Comment: You may be trying to treat English as though it were a completely internally consistent system. No natural language is. Consider, “If you wait long enough, the Sun will expand so much that it will nearly swallow the Earth.” Its **meaning** is scientifically valid, even though its literal wording would suggest that the speaker attributes to the listener a few billion years’ worth of patience.

Answer (score 1):

"dry out soil enough and water will run off it like concrete" means "If you dry out soil enough then water will run off it like concrete", yes.

I suppose you can phrase it generically like X&Y, but the Y and probably also the X need some features to fit into this "if x then y" interpretation. Usually, the phrase in place of Y will include a word like "will" or "going to". I wouldn't know how to stipulate the exact conditions where this phrase can be interpreted this way though, sorry.

edit

I've realized that you're focusing on who is accomplishing the task, I didn't really understand that before. The "You" in "If you dry out..." can be seen as an abstract "you", not actually referring to a real person doing something. "If you went to the center of jupiter, you would find that the gravity is bone-crushingly powerful" -- this isn't saying anything about an actual human who can actually travel to the center of jupiter, it's meant more to be a statement about the center of jupiter. The "you" is abstract/hypothetical - it doesn't have to be remotely possible for a person.`

Comment: Thank you, TKol.  But isn't that like saying "you" have super powers:  nobody can actually dry out enough soil.

Comment: No, it's a dare like Go fight City Hall! An imperative.

Comment: @ForOU I'm not commenting on the practical nature of accomplishing the task, just the natural English interpretation of the text.

Comment: @ForOU I've realized that you're focusing on *who is accomplishing the task*, I didn't really understand that before. The "You" in "If you dry out..." can be seen as an abstract "you", not actually referring to a real person doing something. "If you went to the center of jupiter, you would find that the gravity is bone-crushingly powerful" -- this isn't saying anything about an actual human who can actually travel to the center of jupiter, it's meant more to be a statement about the center of jupiter. The "you" is abstract/hypothetical - it doesn't have to be remotely possible for a person.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).